# When converting content of GET request to BeautifulSoup it gets messed up

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I try to scrape a site (in this case Amazon, but happened in many others too) the content of the GET request turns out fine when looking at it.

```
print(response.content)
```

But when converting it into a BeautifulSoup object the **/body** and the **/html** tags jump up.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
...                # more content that needs to go in the body
```

Edit:
This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myUserAgent = {
        "User-Agent":
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'
    }

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/AOC-I1659FWUX-USB-Powered-Portable-1920x1080/dp/B06Y8SSQG5'

response = requests.get(URL, headers=myUserAgent)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: if you include the url/header combination you're trying it'll greatly improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: It might be because of broken markup. Try using `html5lib` parser and check the difference. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: After debugging I actually did notice that i keep getting **NO_PARSER_SPECIFIED_WARNING**

Comment: so is this solved?

Comment: I couldn't menage to use any downloaded parser, but after converting it from ".content" to ".text" it magically worked